# Named pipes vs. UDP for IPC on Windows

Tags: windows, udp, ipc, named-pipes

Why Named Pipes are preferable for IPC (Inter Process Comunication) on local Windows machine over UDP? Or UDP sometimes might be somewhere better?

Comment: TCP is fine, an unreliable transport mechanism is useless for IPC.

Comment: Please, could you explain what do you mean?

Comment: You first, explain why you want to use UDP.

Comment: Most likely becouse developers of system that should be integrated with our system know what is UDP and don't have experience with Named Pipes. So I have to convince them to learn something new.

Comment: @MajesticRa go TCP then - chances are that developers of the system ... know about TCP even more than about UDP.

Comment: No-no. I  ment that they ARE using UDP for IPC on one machine... I just try to convince them that there are better ways to skin that cat... I know some arguments, but I decided to write the question here to see opinions, better arguments, or maybe even to hear that I'm wrong thinking that UDP is not the perfect way to intaract between processes on the same windows machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UDP packets even on localhost can be lost. Also, as UDP is datagram-based and has no guaranteed delivery, it's hard to transfer larger data blocks. Finally, UDP on localhost is sometimes blocked by browsers. In general, UDP is usually not even considered for single-computer IPC.

On Windows I recommend memory-mapped files + synchronization primitives as the fastest and probably the easiest method. Named pipes usually work well when you manage them to work, but I see lots of questions here regarding how to make the named pipes work at all (and I have yet to see a single complaint regarding MMFs).

We have a product, MsgConnect, which provides socket-, UDP- and MMF-based transports, suitable for IPC locally or across network, so I have practical experience with this topic. Named pipes were considered for support but then the idea was discarded in favor of other mechanisms.

Comment: Named pipes are simple and reliable and more flexible for IPC than memory mapped files. Named pipes ability is built into the .NET environment and easy to use. Named pipes allow you to move your sever or client to any other computer on the network. With memory mapped files you have to manage the synchronization and if you decide you need to move a client or server to another computer you have rewrite your IPC code from the start.

Comment: @NealDavis Named Pipe is never a choice for multiple host communication. The speed of named pipe to remote is very slow.