# need to choose between NamedPipe or UDP

Tags: c#, .net, udp, named-pipes, udpclient

I had an argument with a colleague on the selection.
We have two processes running on the same machine.

=> NamedPipe and UDP are KERNEL OBJECT so as far as i understand this is same overhead.

The advantage of UDP is that if tomorrow we will separate those two processes and they will run on two different computers so I do not have to change anything.

I think that the NamedPipe performance are better since there is no need to use a network card to send the information to the same machine (am I right .. sending localhost will use the network card - right ?)

Can anyone advise us please ??

Thanks

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494993/named-pipes-vs-udp-for-ipc-on-windows

Comment: The network _hardware_ won't be used even with UDP, as long as the I/O is confined to that one machine. The OS is smart enough to route the traffic to itself. But there are other, more important considerations. Kumar's answer does a good job outlining those.

Comment: Not sure how using UDP between two computers is advantage over doing the same with named pipes... Please clarify.

Comment: _"The advantage of UDP is that if tomorrow we will separate those two processes and they will run on two different computers"_ - perhaps. _Native_ pipes will work locally or over the LAN and you won't need to change your app.  If you want to target the LAN and don't want to go native check out .NET's [NamedPipeServerStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085(v=vs.110).aspx).  It is only WCF's `NetNamedPipeBinding` that appears to be localhost-only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Before Implementation , you can care below points :***

**Named pipes:**

1. Named pipes provide interprocess communication between a pipe server and one or more pipe clients.
2. They support message-based communication and allow multiple clients to connect simultaneously to the server process using the same pipe name.
3. Named pipes also support impersonation, which enables connecting processes to use their own permissions on remote servers.

**User Datagram Protocol :**

1. User Datagram Protocol (UDP) is a simple protocol that makes a best effort to deliver data to a remote host.
2. The UDP protocol is a connectionless protocol, UDP datagrams sent to the remote endpoint are not guaranteed to arrive, nor are they guaranteed to arrive in the same sequence in which they are sent.
3. Applications that use UDP must be prepared to handle missing, duplicate, and out-of-sequence datagrams.